# Update UI after Azure WebJob ran

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-webjobs

I have a web job that runs and updates the database after receive a queue message. This message is usually trigger as part of a certain process in an ASP.NET MVC application.

Now I want to add a button on the UI so that the user can then queue a message for the job to run, but I want to update the view, for the user that triggered the job, with the result from the azure webjob.

I initially thought of WebHooks, but that is not what webhooks are designed for. The only other thing I can think of, is maybe something like SignalR.

This is not an overly long task running in the WebJob, but there is a good reason it was decoupled in this way, and I want to make use of this same code without duplication.

I can also poll the database to see if the data updated, but I don't really want to do this because if no data has been updated, I won't really know that the job has finished. Polling is just the wrong way of approaching this.

So in essence, the following happens:
User request update -> update request added to queue -> WebJobs triggers and process request -> Page for the user is updated with the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> User request update -> update request added to queue -> WebJobs triggers and process request -> Page for the user is updated with the result

SignalR is a library that could be used to develop real-time web functionality, you could call hub method to update web app UI from your WebJob. If you’d like to save/update data to your SQL database and broadcast updates notification to the browser, you could use [SignalR and SQL Dependency](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/883702/real-time-notifications-using-signalr-and-sql-depe) to build a real-time notification solution. Besides, this blog explained how to [communicate from an Azure WebJob to your website with SignalR](http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/communicate-from-azure-webjob-with-signalr/), please refer to it.